# How can I check if firestore rules are rolled out

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I am modeling security rules with firestore right now and deploy them with

```
firebase deploy --only firestore:rules
```

Unfortunately it takes a while after the deploy before the rules are in effect. I now wonder how I can check that. My problem is that I am in the middle of development and constantly modify the rules and want to run tests against them. But now I don't know if my tests fail because the rules are broken or not yet rolled out which is really annoying.

Comment: I believe there's no way to test the rules yet. But have in mind that Firestore is still in Beta, which means we might get some kind of rules simulator soon (when it gets stable). They might even reduce the amount of time it takes to deploy the rules.